# Override bold fonts with normal fonts

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

For any applied theme, I want to override the bold fonts with normal fonts. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using Emacs 24's built-in themes,

my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620613/customizing-emacs-syntax-coloring) question applies pretty well.  Something like this (untested):

```
(defun debold-font-lock ()
  "remove all colors from font-lock faces except comment and warning"
  (mapc (lambda (face)
          (when face
            (set-face-bold-p face nil)))
        (face-list)))

(debold-font-lock)
```

You can add this to `load-theme` with an advice if you need it to always happen.

EDIT: I mentioned an advice above, but it's generally better to not advice if
you can help it.

So we can define a new function:

```
(defun load-theme-no-bold ()
  (interactive)
  (call-interactively 'load-theme)
  (debold-font-lock))
```

Map this function to a key as required or call it directly from M-x.

EDIT: Advice info.

In Emacs you can change the way any function works using the advice mechanism.

You think "P" should be inserted with the key <kbd>a</kbd> is pressed?  No problem.

See [docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Advice.html).

Because this is a powerful tool, it tends to get trotted out a lot, but really
it should only be applied as a last resort, because you never know what
packages out there depend on the existing behaviour.

Comment: Can you please clarify the last sentence? I am unable to understand it.